# XMLAGG Throws Inconsistent Datatypes: Expected - got CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

In the first place, my query (actually subquery, continue on reading) contains a `LISTAGG`, but I need to replace it with `XMLAGG` when users are started to get `result of string concatenation is too long` errors.

So, here is my subquery. I'm not sharing the whole query, because first it is too long and second its not so relevant with what I'm asking. I'll provide the data types nevertheless.

```
(select rtrim((xmlagg(xmlelement(e, sa1.answer || ',') order by sa1.answer).EXTRACT('//text()')).getclobval(), ',')
 from social_feed_answer sa1 where sa1.docid = f.id and sa1.issent = 1 and sa1.answertype in
 ('Reply', 'PrivateMessage', 'ApproveFeed','RejectFeed') and sa1.isactive = 1) as Answers,
```

Before your suggestions, I have already tried to remove `RTRIM` and `ORDER BY` clauses. None of them helps. I got different types of error e.g. `Conversion of special character to escaped character failed` or `Character string buffer too small error`.

My oracle version is 19c and that `sa1.answer` is `nvarchar(2000)`.

I saw that this query works on other people flawless, but cannot figure out what's the case for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One issue appears to be that `sa1.answer || ','` raises an exception and not that there is a problem with `XMLAGG`. To fix that you can use `EMPTY_CLOB() || sa1.answer || ','` or `TO_CLOB(sa1.answer) || ','` so that the first value is a `CLOB`, and not a `NVARCHAR2`, and then the concatenated string will not be too large.

```sql
select rtrim(
         xmlagg(
           xmlelement(e, EMPTY_CLOB() || sa1.answer || ',')
           order by sa1.answer
         ).EXTRACT('//text()').getclobval(),
         ','
       )
from   social_feed_answer sa1
-- ...
```

or:

```sql
select rtrim(
         xmlagg(
           xmlelement(e, TO_CLOB(sa1.answer) || ',')
           order by sa1.answer
         ).EXTRACT('//text()').getclobval(),
         ','
       )
from   social_feed_answer sa1
-- ...
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb2ef682f25ba15696efab7ebee718ec)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunally, none of them worked out on me. I have also checked your fiddle link, but couldn't figure out what is the problem on my case. Still getting `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB` error on the same line

Answer (score 0):

```
(select xmlagg(xmlelement(e, REGEXP_REPLACE(sa1.answer, '[^[:print:]]', '') || ' , ') 
order by sa1.answer).EXTRACT('//text()') from social_feed_answer sa1  where sa1.docid = f.id and sa1.issent = 1 and sa1.answertype in 
('Reply', 'PrivateMessage', 'ApproveFeed', 'RejectFeed') and sa1.isactive = 1) as Answers
```

Above query works out without any issue.

`REGEXP_REPLACE` function is necessary *only if* your are facing `ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed` error. And, have to give up `RTRIM` function as this function converts the result type to VARCHAR2 which  might makes you end up with `result of string concatenation is too long` error (by the way, `getClobVal()` right after `XMLAGG` didn't help).